# Product flavour [Migrating from eclipse to android studio]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors

I have migrated my app from eclipse to android studio, and now I was attempting to run product flavours.
I have been following the blog at [http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/ultiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/)

Following is my build structure when imported from eclipse.
[image: EclipsetoStudioBuildStructure]

I am able to see the variants in the build variants window.

Following is the build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true;
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt');
        }
    }

    productFlavors {

        demo {
            applicationId "com.demo.app"
        }

    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false;
        abortOnError false;
    }
}
```

I want the Constants.java file to be available for different flavours as it has different values for the respective flavours.

Following is the build structure as seen in general studio projects

```
app/
|--libs/
|--src/
   |--vanilla/
   |  |--java/
   |     |--com/example/
   |        |--Flavor.java
   |--strawberry/
   |  |--java/
   |     |--com/example/
   |        |--Flavor.java
   |--main/
      |--java/
      |  |--...
      |--res/
      |  |--...
      |--AndroidManifest.xml
```

But the structure when migrated from eclipse seems to be totally different.
I tried to make a directory in src [demo/com.demo.app]to check the flavour variant. But its not working. Can anyone guide me on this ? How do i go about including product flavour support for projects migrated from eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import a project from Eclipse, Android Studio keeps the same folder structure so your source doesn't move around too much.

This means that you won't be able to use the default source locations. This is why your build.gradle has the `sourceSets` closure:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
}
```

This block sets up the location for all of your default code (the `main` configuration).

If you don't want to change your project structure, you can add another block within `sourceSets` for your flavor. The following example will allow you to put all the code for your `demo` flavor under `demo/src`:

```
sourceSets {
        main {}
        demo {
            manifest.srcFile 'demo/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['demo/src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['demo/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['demo/src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['demo/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['demo/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['demo/assets']
        }
}
```

The other alternative is to remove the `sourceSets` closure completely and update your project structure to match the standard structure for Gradle-backed project.

Comment: That sounds perfect. I will try the solution and accept the answer .. Cheers :)

Comment: After including the source sets as you mentioned,I am facing duplicate classes in the respective flavours while compiling. 'error duplicate class:com.demo.app.Constants'

Comment: It sounds like you have a `Constants` class in both your main and demo source sets. All code in the main source set is included for all variants, whereas code in other source sets (such as demo) are only included in their respective variants. Thus if you have a `Constants` in both, you'll end up with two conflicting copies of the same class. It sounds like you might want a `release` source set with the release constants and a `demo` source set with the demo constants.