# Migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, migrate

I searched and I could not find the answer to my problem. There was a solution that seemed valid, but could not use it in AS 2.1.1 (latest) - [Product flavour [Migrating from eclipse to android studio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074802/product-flavour-migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio/31075091#31075091)

My issue is as follows:

A senior dev started a project in Eclipse, the project has grown a lot and now he left. I have to migrate the project in AS to be able to add new stuff and this killed.

I started with going into Eclipse and Exporting the project for Gradle. I went into AS and imported the project.

All seems well so far, but now comes the fun part: the project was building on a separate machine, using different configs for each flavor. In AS I was not able to do so. I will attach here my config maybe someone can help. I need each flavor with a different assets folder that will contain the config file, and a different manifest, as each version can have different names / strings. The rest of the code should be common so it can be easily modified for all version.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    productFlavors {
        v1 {
            //manifest.srcFile 'src/v1/AndroidManifest.xml'
            //assets.srcDirs = ['src/v1/assets'] 
        }

        v2 {
            //manifest.srcFile 'src/v2/AndroidManifest.xml'
            //assets.srcDirs = ['src/v2/assets'] 
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        v1 {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/v1/AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/v1/assets'] 
        }

        v2 {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/v2/AndroidManifest.xml'
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/v2/assets'] 
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```